# jQuery Mobile / Phonegap - Select menu won't open on android

Tags: android, html, css, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am using JQM 1.1.1 and phonegap 2.0 and I have this problem with select menus.
They wont open on android (95% of the time) but work fine in iOS.

I have tried all the fixes out there ([webkit-backface-visibility](http://blogs.bytecode.com.au/glen/2011/07/14/eliminating-annoying-flicker-transitions-with.html), removing absolute/relative positions from buttons) but for no avail.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

This is known bug on jquery mobile, and unfortunately they haven't fix it yet. select box stop working in android when u fixed the header or footer and use select box in them . if you use select box outside the fixed header or footer it will work fine.